# Remove lm from one group ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df:

```
MixA<-c(11.3296500, 3.7765500, 13.2179250, 1.8882750, 60.4248063, 906.3720938, 483.3984500, 1450.1953500, 0.4130875, 0.0590125)
TPM<-c(496.510998, 121.020332, 32.194033, 0.584421, 63.569152, 253.681165, 0.000000, 30487.460466, 0.000000, 0.000000)
test<-data.frame(MixA,TPM)
```

I want to log so I arbitarily replace the zeros and I want to plot these 'zero' points in a seperate colour so I group the data:

```
test[test == 0]<-0.01
test$group<-as.factor(ifelse(test$TPM==1.000000e-02,0,1))
```

When I plot with ggplot and it plots a lm for both groups but I want to remove the lm for the 'zero' group.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=log10(test$MixA),y=log10(test$TPM),color=group))  + geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 3)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 5))  +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I tried adding aes(group=1) to geom_smooth but this seems to shift the whole line??:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=log10(test$MixA),y=log10(test$TPM),color=group))  + geom_point(size=3) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 3)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 5))  +geom_smooth(aes(group=1), method="lm")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Would it work for you if you `filter` the data and then plot ? `test %>%
  filter(group != 0) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x=log10(MixA),y=log10(TPM),color=group)  + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 3)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 5))  +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
`

Comment: My understanding is that this doesn't plot the 'zero' group? I want to plot the 'zero' group but without the lm

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `geom_smooth()` statement to reflect the groups for which you wish to plot a line.

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x=log10(MixA),y=log10(TPM),color=group))  + geom_point(size=3) +
geom_smooth(data = subset(test, group == 1), aes(x= log10(MixA),y= log10(TPM),color=group), method=lm) + 
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 3)) + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2.5, 5))  +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This should give you the plot you want.

[image: Remove lm for one group in ggplot2]
Best.